# How do I disable email address autocomplete in Lotus Notes 9

Tags: email, autocomplete

I currently use IBM Notes v9 Social Addition and I want to disable the email address autocomplete functionality to prevent emails being accidentally sent to the wrong recipient.

What is the best way to achieve this please?

Comment: Select File, from the Menu Bar, Preferences and User Preferences from the menu.
Check your Use inline AutoComplete setting in the Additional Options Window ...